# Can I play GTA 5 story mode with no wifi connection?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-network

I won't have a wifi connection for a while, is there any way I can pick up the game where I left it without connecting to xbox live and without starting it over? And if not, can I still save the progress if I do start it over? I have an xbox 360.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I play with no internet connection too. You dont need to be connected to save/load your progress in story mode.